# Experience Site language change for logged users

Tags: lightning-community, site.com

I've been having some issues and wanted to see if it happens to someone else.

Basically I have an experience site, users log in, and they have their language set (say, fr_CA or en_CA), thing is, users that are en_CA can change the language to fr_CA without changing it on their users (basically just changing the ?language=en_CA to ?language=fr_CA in the url) but users that are fr_CA on the user, cannot do the same and show en_CA without changing their user, is there any particular reason for this? Got me really confused. Maybe it's because english is the default language for the site? I tested adding a third language (es_CL) and fr_CA users can change to es_CL but still cannot do so to en_CA, it would be great for me to be able to achieve this without having to update records in salesforce.

Hope anyone can help me, and thanks in advance!

King regards

TLDR(hope it helps to clarify issue)
Experience Site users are able to change the page language without having to change the User language using the ?language parameter in URL, but only to non-site-default languages.

Comment: So after running more tests, it does seem related to the default language on site, I changed it to French and it allowed french users to switch to en_CA but now en_CA users cannot change to fr_CA. Would like to know if someone knows the reason behind this and if there is a config for it, other than a possible workaround to set an unused language as default so users can handle this normally. Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: what happens when fr_CA user set the url to en_CA? are they redirected or just the language fall back to default?

Comment: They are redirected, like if you use ?language=en_CA it automatically loads ?language=fr_CA again, doing logs show that for example you attempting to load en_CA but when the page starts loading it's already fr_CA.

Third languages are able to change between each other but not to the default site language.